# How to insert rows in datagridview which is placed on form2 in vb.net as add button is on form1?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

```
 Private Sub btn_add_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btn_add.Click
        Dim Query As String
        mysqlconn.Open()
        Query = "insert into details(id,s1,c1)values('" & txt_.Text & "','" & txt1.Text & "','" & txt2.Text & "')"
        Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand(Query, mysqlconn)
        Dim i As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

        mysqlconn.Close()

        If (i > 0) Then
            MsgBox("Record is Successfully added")
            mysqlconn.Open()

            Dim strSQL As String = "SELECT * from details "
            Dim cmd1 As New MySqlCommand(strSQL, mysqlconn)
            Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = cmd1.ExecuteReader
            Dim table1 As New DataTable()
            table1.Load(reader)
            datagridview1.DataSource = table1
            ' datagridview1.RefreshEdit()
            mysqlconn.Close()
            mysqlconn.Dispose()
        Else
            MsgBox("Record is not added")
        End If
        mysqlconn.Close()
end sub
```

I have two forms: `Form1` and `Form2`.

`Form1` - In the above code, after I click on add button, id, txt1, txt2 which are entered in textboxes are saved into the details table.(mysql database)

At the same time I want to insert that entry in datagridview which is placed on `Form2`.

I have written some code after msgbox "successfully added". I am not getting an error when executing the same code, but row is not getting added in datagridview during runtime.

Comment: There must be a datagridview1 on the same form as your button, otherwise the IDE would throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

You just want to add the same thing to the data grid view?

```
Form2.datagridview.rows.add( New Object() {Value1, value2, value3})
```

Each comma represents a different column in the row.

You can manipulate the DGV from wherever.